# Get uptime in seconds or miliseconds on Unix like systems

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I need a method which can give me the number of miliseconds or seconds, elapsed since the system was started.
I could parse `/proc/uptime` , but i can't afford to lose performance over this I/0 and parsing.

I'm using Linux and C/C++. Maybe i can put some Qt/Boost, but is better to be something native.

Comment: OS boot uptime or your application uptime?

Comment: check post below, guy said it right, use sysinfo.h,  i am unsure about you wanting milliseconds as `uptime` in sysinfo returns value in seconds

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why cannot you afford reading `/proc/uptime`? It is *not a real file* so reading it should be quick (there is no real i/o involved, since the `/proc/` filesystem contains pseudo-files). Did you benchmark its reading?

You might also call [clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`

NB. This is specific to Linux.

Comment: /proc files are not disk files, good answer.  /proc lives in kernel.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [sysinfo.h](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_sysinfo.htm).