# c++ Linux TickCount

Tags: c++, linux

Is there a similar function like GetTickCount() for Linux?

I´ve tried out some other sutff, but they didn´t work at all.

So it should return the exact time in milliseconds since startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) with CLOCK_MONOTONIC is the magic incantation you [seem to be looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357073/get-uptime-in-seconds-or-miliseconds-on-unix-like-systems). Sample code, untested:

```
struct timespec *t;
t = (struct timespec *)malloc(sizeof(t)); 
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, t);
```

Let me know how you get on. I'm not on Linux at the moment, hence this is just conjecture from the man page I pointed to.

Comment: hmm well compiler says it doesn´t exists, but I included time.h

Comment: try #include <linux/time.h>?

Comment: got it now, but it doesnt work: struct timespec ts_tick;
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_tick);
 ret = ts_tick.tv_nsec;

Comment: What do you expect and what's it giving you?

Comment: A solution, why it doesnt store the nano seconds in the long variable ret

Comment: Fallacious example, with a BUG. clock_gettime wants a pointer to timespec, here is passed a pointer to pointer ...

Comment: You can post an edit, @Massimo, and I will gladly accept, instead of being rude about it.

Answer (score 6):

```
/// Returns the number of ticks since an undefined time (usually system startup).
static uint64_t GetTickCountMs()
{
    struct timespec ts;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);

    return (uint64_t)(ts.tv_nsec / 1000000) + ((uint64_t)ts.tv_sec * 1000ull);
}
```

Also useful...

```
/// Computes the elapsed time, in milliseconds, between two 'timespec'.
inline uint32_t TimeElapsedMs(const struct timespec& tStartTime, const struct timespec& tEndTime)
{
   return 1000*(tEndTime.tv_sec - tStartTime.tv_sec) +
          (tEndTime.tv_nsec - tStartTime.tv_nsec)/1000000;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The accepted one is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

> hmm well compiler says it doesn´t exists, but I included time.h

Does it give you a compiler or a linker error?
If you get a linker error, it might be because you haven't linked with 'rt' library.